# QListWidget resize contents when splitter changes size

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, sizehint

I have a QListWidget with some widgets inside:

```
QListWidgetItem* w = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
ui->listWidget->addItem(w);
w->setSizeHint(widget->sizeHint());
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(w, widget);
```

However, everything seems to work fine until I resize the the `QListWidget` (it is embedded into a `QDockwidget`). Do I have to iterate over all items and resize them manually or is there a simple trick?

It is just a list with items having a button on the left and a button on the right. If the list gets resized (`QSize` changes) than the buttons gets hidden and a scrollbar appears. I want to have the size of the item according to the list width.

Comment: use a layout for the QDockwidget

Comment: @ratchetfreak I already do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `resizeMode` property to `Adjust`.  This will cause your `QListWidget` to automatically resize all of the items in the view to the size of the `QListWidget` anytime the widget is resized.

See the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop).  Your code will be structured like so:

```
QListWidgetItem* w = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
w->setSizeHint(widget->sizeHint());
ui->listWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
ui->listWidget->addItem(w);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(w, widget);
```

EDIT: Depending on the uniformity of your items, you may also benefit from setting the [uniformItemSizes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#uniformItemSizes-prop) property.  `QListView` can optimize the layout of your view if you set this property.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have a listWidget of QLabels and set listWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);. When I resize the window, the text in each QLabel wraps properly depending on the width, but the listWidget does not addjust the distance between them, so that there are no gaps. It always keeps the initial size between the QLabels.